# Server side processing in Datatables using Yii

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I want to implement Datatables in my Yii project. I set up everything by the manual. Here is my jQuery for init:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#drugs').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/products/retrievedata',
                type: 'POST'
            }
        });
    } );
```

And I can't come up with code in Yii for getting the data. My main objective is to make an ajax live search in my mysql DB,

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use CGridView if you are processing Data tables on server side.

Comment: What do you mean? Is there an ajax data pre-loading and ajax filtering?

Comment: Yes, Please go through http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/